# How to make local notification actions directly delete To-Do Items in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I have a Table View Controller project in Swift.
I would need 2 Local Notification actions: one to complete and delete a deadline to-do item, and the other one to open a View Controller of the app.
I have already added `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver` for the actions but I'm still wondering how to delete the to-do items from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. using just the the notification actions.
I hope you could help me! Thank you in advance!

*Here are some parts of my codes:*

AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Actions
    var firstAction:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    firstAction.identifier = "FIRST_ACTION"
    firstAction.title = "Complete" // "First Action"

    firstAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    firstAction.destructive = true
    firstAction.authenticationRequired = false

    var secondAction:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    secondAction.identifier = "SECOND_ACTION"
    secondAction.title = "Edit" // "Second Action"

    secondAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
    secondAction.destructive = false
    secondAction.authenticationRequired = false

    var thirdAction:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    thirdAction.identifier = "THIRD_ACTION"
    thirdAction.title = "Third Action"

    thirdAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    thirdAction.destructive = false
    thirdAction.authenticationRequired = false


    // category

    var firstCategory:UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    firstCategory.identifier = "FIRST_CATEGORY"

    let defaultActions:NSArray = [firstAction, secondAction, thirdAction]
    let minimalActions:NSArray = [firstAction, secondAction]

    firstCategory.setActions(defaultActions as! [UIUserNotificationAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    firstCategory.setActions(minimalActions as! [UIUserNotificationAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)

    // NSSet of all our categories

    let categories:NSSet = NSSet(objects: firstCategory)



    let types:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType(arrayLiteral: .Alert, .Badge)

    let mySettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: categories as! Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(mySettings)



func application(application: UIApplication!,
    handleActionWithIdentifier identifier:String!,
    forLocalNotification notification:UILocalNotification!,
    completionHandler: (() -> Void)!){


        if (identifier == "First_Action"){


            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionOnePressed", object: nil)




        }else  if (identifier == "Second_Action"){

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionTwoPressed", object: nil)


        }


        completionHandler()
```

ToDoTableViewController:

```
// 
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "drawAShape", name: "actionOnePressed", object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showAMessage", name: "actionTwoPressed", object: nil)

//
let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: todoItems.count, inSection: 0)
todoItems.append(todoItem)
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)         

//scheduleLocalNotification(todoItem)
let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
notification.category = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
notification.alertBody = "Notification \(todoItem.title)"
notification.fireDate = fixNotificationDate(todoItem.deadline)
notification.userInfo = ["note":todoItem.note, "title": todoItem.title]

         UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are not passing anything between `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:` and the functions to do something. Therefore those functions don't know what to do.

The `identifier` you pass needs to provide enough information to identify what to do. For example it might be "delete=123" to delete record 123. Then you would pass this in the postNotification:

```
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionTwoPressed",
         object: nil, userInfo: identifier)
```

Now you want to pick it up in the handler for the `actionTwoPressed` notification, which for you is `showAMessage`, so it will need a parameter:

```
    func showAMessage(notification: NSNotification) {
        // notification.userInfo is the identifier
    }
```

This also means you need to change the addObserver, including the ":" to show a parameter is passed:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "showAMessage", name: "actionTwoPressed:", object: nil)
```

Also, none of this code would be in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I've already done that! But I don't know how to make `func showAMessage()` delete the **todoItems** from `indexPath`. I have already tried something like: `todoItems.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)` like it is to `commitEditingStyle`, but no results.